# Ory/hydra login page redirect url with a simple spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, redirect, oauth-2.0, ory-hydra

I have a common login page for different applications which uses jwt token and when I want to call this component's rest API I have to put the jwt to the header to get the user_info. I have multiple application that uses this component and it will be easier if I can use a common Oauth2 server for this purpose.

I started to use ory/hydra and I don't really understand how does it work. I downloaded it and run on on localhost with port 4444 and 4445 (admin) with hydra serve all command.
After that in another command line I run the following line:

> $ hydra clients create --skip-tls-verify --endpoint 'https://localhost:4445' --id client_id --secret secret -c 'https://localhost:8082/login/oauth2/code/' -a 'user_info'

The login page that I can use looks like : 'https://loginpage.../login.html?redirect_url='
What should be the redirect url in this case? (I will have multiple spring boot app)

hydra.yml:

```
log:
    level: info
    format: json
serve:
    public:
        port: 4444
        host: speacial-host

    admin:
        port: 4445
        host: speacial-host

dsn: memory

webfinger:

  jwks:
    broadcast_keys:
      - hydra.jwt.access-token # This key will be exposed when the OAuth2 Access Token strategy is set to JWT.
  oidc_discovery:
      - user_info
    userinfo_url: http://restapi_url:8080/backend/api/user_info

urls:
    self:
        issuer: https://speacial-host:4444/
        public: https://speacial-host:4444/
    login: https://loginpage.../login.html?redirect_url=https://127.0.0.1:4444/oauth/callback

oauth2:
  expose_internal_errors: true

profiling: cpu
```

I need the oauth server to handle the jwt token. So when I have to call the REST API I need would like to call for the oauth server for this purpose.

Spring boot app application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 8082
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        name: UISESSION
spring:
  thymeleaf:
    cache: false
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          custom-client:
            client-id: client_id
            client-secret: secret
            client-name: Auth Server
            scope: user_info
            provider: custom-provider
            redirect-uri: https://127.0.0.1:4444/oauth/callback
            client-authentication-method: basic
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
        provider:
          custom-provider:
            token-uri: https://localhost:4444/oauth2/token
            authorization-uri: https://localhost:4444/oauth2/auth
            user-info-uri: https://localhost:4444/userinfo
            user-name-attribute: name
```

Is there any config parameter that I missed?